# Probability of never getting k tails in infinite flips

Tags: probability

I am currently trying to solve a problem but am at a standstill. The question is:
If a coin is flipped infinitely many times, what is the probability that there will never be j successive tails?
I have a recursive sequence of a_n, where a_n is the number of ways of flipping a coin n times without having successive j tails.

The recursive sequence is:
an=a(n-1) + a(n-2) + ... + a(n-j) (this is all based on the flips and what sequence the flips generate).

Now I am asked to prove that a_n < c^n for some c<2 for every n>=(j+1).
Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: the probability will be 1. funfact: there will be infinite long tails-sequences aswell as heads-sequences

Comment: Sorry asked the wrong question!

Comment: @saturatedexpo Wrong, the length of every tails-sequence and every heads-sequence will be finite.

Comment: @Did mmh, can you elobrate on that? can't infinities contain smaller infinities? the original question was infinite flips.

Comment: @saturatedexpo Elaborate on what? Let me repeat: there is never infinitely many consecutive tails and there is never infinitely many consecutive heads.

Comment: @Did my thought process is: 1 consecutive head will appear in such tossing-fest, 2 consecutive heads will appear, 3..., n will appear. let n go to infinity? (obv no proof lol, just the idea i mean)

Comment: @saturatedexpo For every n, there will be n consecutive heads (and furthermore, this will happen infinitely often). "Letting n go to infinity" is poetry in the bad sense of the term.

Comment: @Did okay, if for every n $\in$ N there will be n consecutive heads, then why is it not okay to talk about $n\rightarrow \infty$ ? To my understanding N has no biggest number, so calling n arbitrarily large or infinity makes no difference _to me_.

Comment: A property being true for n arbitrarily large or for n = infinity makes all the difference in the world. Example: The property [There exists a finite set of size n] is true for n arbitrarily large but not for n = infinity.

Comment: @Did that is indeed a catchy example. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

If you flip a coin with a nonzero probability of tails an infinite (either countable or uncountable, doesn't matter) number of times, then the probability of obtaining $j$ successive tails is always $1$ for $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I omitted a part out of the question. Now I am asked to prove that a_n<c^n for some c<2 for every n>=(j+1). How do I prove this? Using induction?

Comment: I fixed the comment to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we flip a coin $j$ times, and the chance that any flip lands tails is $p \in (0,1)$.  Then, assuming that individual flips are independent, the probability that all flips land tails is simply $p^j$.  Let's call such a group of flips a single **trial**.  Consequently, if we repeat this experiment $n$ times--i.e., we conduct $n$ trials--the probability that none of the trials results in $j$ consecutive tails is $(1 - p^j)^n$.

Now, observe that the event that any $j$ consecutive tails, including those that may have started in one trial and ended in the next, is a strict superset of the aforementioned event, it follows that the probability in $N = nj$ flips of not observing $j$ consecutive tails is **at least** $(1 - p^j)^n$.  Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$, we find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 - p^j)^n = 0,$$ since $0 < p < 1$ implies $0 < p^j < 1$, which implies $1 > 1 - p^j > 0$.  Therefore, the probability of avoiding eventually observing $j \ge 1$ consecutive flips--**no matter how large $j$ is**--is zero.